# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 error

Tags: java, exception, awt-eventqueue

So I'm having trouble with an application I've been working on and I only saw one other post with the -1 error and doesn't seem to help me with what is going on.  We have an items tab that when you click on a consignor, it should display the items and it does, but it spits out this error and sometimes doesn't update.

Error:

```
   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at com.GiggaFriggs.ItemPanel$5.valueChanged(ItemPanel.java:502)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.clearSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setModel(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setListData(Unknown Source)
at com.GiggaFriggs.ItemPanel.refreshItemList(ItemPanel.java:533)
at com.GiggaFriggs.ItemPanel$4.valueChanged(ItemPanel.java:460)
at javax.swing.JList.fireSelectionValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList$ListSelectionHandler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.adjustSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code:

```
package com.GiggaFriggs;


import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ItemPanel extends JPanel {


    protected static int conID;

    private int itemID;
    private JLabel itemIdLabel;
    private JTextField searchTF;
    private JRadioButton conRB, dealRB;
    private ButtonGroup searchBG;
    private JButton searchB;
    protected static JList <String> conList;
    private static JList <String> itemList;
    private JScrollPane itemPane;
    private String[] sampleItemA;
    private JFormattedTextField priceTF;
    private JTextField itemDesTF;
    private JFormattedTextField lowPriceTF;
    private JComboBox<?> categoryCB;
    final private String[] categoryListA = { "Home Decor", "Womens Accessories", "Furniture", "Collectables"};
    private JTextField commentsTF;
    private static final String IMG_PATH = "src/images/testImage.jpg";

    protected static String[] conSampleList;
    private JLabel priceL;
    private JLabel lowPriceL;
    private JButton saveB;
    private JButton newB;
    private JButton deleteB;
    private JButton sellB;
    protected static Consigner[] consignerList;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private static int conMarker;

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://173.194.80.143:3306/Test";
    static Connection conn = null;
    static Statement stmt = null;
    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    public ItemPanel(){

        conMarker = 0;
        consignerList = DatabaseConnector.pullConInfoDB();
        conSampleList = new String[consignerList.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < conSampleList.length; i++){
        conSampleList[i] = "ID " + String.valueOf(consignerList[i].getIdNumber() + "     " + consignerList[i].getLastName() + ", " + consignerList[i].getFirstName());
        }
        //consignerID = consignerList[0].getIdNumber();

        searchTF = new JTextField("Search for Consigner/Dealer");
        searchB = new JButton("Search");
        conList = new JList<String>(conSampleList);
        conList.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        conList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        conList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(conList);
        sampleItemA = new String[consignerList[conMarker].items.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleItemA.length; i++){
            if(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].isSold() == false)
            sampleItemA[i] = consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemDesc();
        }

        itemList = new JList<String>(sampleItemA);
        itemList.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        itemList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        itemList.setSelectedIndex(0);
        itemPane = new JScrollPane(itemList);
        itemIdLabel = new JLabel("Item # " + Integer.toString(itemID));
        itemDesTF = new JTextField(consignerList[conMarker].items[0].getItemDesc());
        itemDesTF.setColumns(21);
        categoryCB= new JComboBox<String>(categoryListA);
        categoryCB.setSelectedItem(consignerList[conMarker].items[0].getCategory());
        priceTF = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        priceTF.setColumns(5);
        priceTF.setValue(consignerList[conMarker].items[0].getSalePrice());
        lowPriceTF = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance());
        lowPriceTF.setValue(consignerList[conMarker].items[0].getLowBid());
        lowPriceTF.setColumns(5);
        priceL = new JLabel("Requested Price");
        lowPriceL = new JLabel("Lowest Price Accepted");
        commentsTF = new JTextField(consignerList[conMarker].items[0].getComments());
        conRB = new JRadioButton("Consigner", true);
        dealRB = new JRadioButton("Dealer", false);
        searchBG = new ButtonGroup();
        searchBG.add(conRB);
        searchBG.add(dealRB);
        saveB = new JButton("Save/Edit");
        newB = new JButton("New Item");
        deleteB = new JButton("Delete Item");
        sellB = new JButton("Sell Item");
        saveB.setDefaultCapable(true);
        saveB.getPreferredSize();


    }

    public static int getConMarker() {
        return conMarker;
    }


    protected JPanel createItemsPanel(){

        JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        outerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        //adding constraints to items and adding them to the panel
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        outerPanel.add(searchTF, c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        outerPanel.add(searchB, c);

        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        outerPanel.add(conRB, c);

        c.gridx =1;
        outerPanel.add(dealRB, c);

        c.gridy =2;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        outerPanel.add(scrollPane, c);

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        c2.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        TitledBorder titled = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Item Information");
        innerPanel.setBorder(titled);

        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 0;
        c2.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        innerPanel.add(itemIdLabel, c2);


        c2.gridx = 1;
        c2.gridwidth = 2;

        innerPanel.add(itemPane, c2);


        //this is how you show an image
//      try{
//          BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG_PATH));
//          ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
//          pictureLabel = new JLabel(icon);
//          
//      } catch (IOException e){
//          e.printStackTrace();
//      }

//      c2.gridx = 4;
//      c2.gridwidth = 1;
//      innerPanel.add(pictureLabel, c2);

        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy=1;
        c2.gridwidth = 2;
        innerPanel.add(itemDesTF, c2);

        c2.gridx = 2;
        c2.gridwidth = 1;
        innerPanel.add(categoryCB, c2);

        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 2;
        innerPanel.add(priceL, c2);

        c2.gridx = 2;
        c2.gridwidth = 1;
        innerPanel.add(priceTF, c2);

        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 3;
        innerPanel.add(lowPriceL, c2);

        c2.gridwidth = 1;
        c2.gridx = 2;
        innerPanel.add(lowPriceTF, c2);

        c2.gridwidth = 3;
        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy =4;
        innerPanel.add(commentsTF, c2);

        c2.gridwidth = 1;
        c2.gridx = 0;
        c2.gridy = 5;
        innerPanel.add(saveB, c2);

        c2.gridx = 1;
        innerPanel.add(deleteB, c2);

        c2.gridx = 2;
        innerPanel.add(newB, c2);

        c2.gridx = 3;
        innerPanel.add(sellB, c2);

        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 5;
        outerPanel.add(innerPanel, c);

        EditHandler eh = new EditHandler();
        saveB.addActionListener(eh);
        SearchingHands sh = new SearchingHands();
        searchB.addActionListener(sh);
        searchTF.addActionListener(sh);

        newB.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        conMarker = (int) conList.getSelectedIndex();
                        consignerList = DatabaseConnector.pullConInfoDB();
                        System.out.println(conMarker);
                        System.out.println(consignerList[conMarker].itemsForSale());

                        if (consignerList[conMarker].itemsForSale() < 15 ){
                        NewItem ni = new NewItem();
                        ni.setUpInter();
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Sorry",
                                    "This Consignor already has 15 items for sale",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                    }

                });

        deleteB.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int x = (int) itemList.getSelectedIndex();
                        String temp = itemIdLabel.getText();
                        String temp2 = temp.substring(7);
                        int i = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
                        System.out.println(i);

                        String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                null,
                                "Why are you deleting this item?",
                                "Deleting " + consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getItemDesc(),
                                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                null, null, "Explain Yourself!!!");


                        try{
                            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "swingset");
                            stmt=conn.createStatement();

                            String sq1 = "UPDATE items SET itemStatus = 'D', itemComments = '" + input + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;

                            stmt.executeUpdate(sq1);

                            conn.close();

                        } catch (SQLException ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }catch(Exception er){
                            er.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        consignerList[conMarker].items[x].setSold(true);

                        refreshConList();
                        refreshItemList(conMarker);


//                      
//                      Object[] options = {"Yes",
//                      "No"};
//                      int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
//                          "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
//                          "Delete Item?",
//                          JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
//                          JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
//                          null,     //do not use a custom Icon
//                          options,  //the titles of buttons
//                          options[0]); //default button title
//                      
//                      if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
//                      
//                          try{
//                              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//                              
//                              conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "swingset");
//                              stmt=conn.createStatement();
//                              
//                              String sq1 = "DELETE FROM items WHERE itemID = " + i;
//                              stmt.executeUpdate(sq1);
//                              
//                              conn.close();
//                              
//                          } catch (SQLException ex){
//                              ex.printStackTrace();
//                          }catch(Exception er){
//                              er.printStackTrace();
//                          }


                        }

                    }

                );
        sellB.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        int x = (int) itemList.getSelectedIndex();
                        double soldFor = 0.00;
                        String input = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                            null,
                                            "How much are you selling " 
                                                    + consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getItemDesc() + " for?",
                                            "Selling " + consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getItemDesc(),
                                            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                                            null, null, "$00.00");

//                      String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Selling " + consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getItemDesc(), "How much are you selling " 
//                              + consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getItemDesc() + "for?");

                        try{
                        soldFor = Double.parseDouble(input);

                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Please Enter a Number.",
                                    "That is not a Number!!!!",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }

                        if (soldFor >= consignerList[conMarker].items[x].getLowBid()){ 

                            consignerList[conMarker].items[x].sellItem(soldFor);

                            String temp = itemIdLabel.getText();
                            String temp2 = temp.substring(7);
                            int i = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
                            Date d = new Date();
                            String soldDate = sdf.format(d);
                            //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyy");
                            //Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                            //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 90);
                            //consignerList[conMarker].items[x].setCreatedOn(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

                            try{
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "*****", "*******");
                                stmt=conn.createStatement();

                                String sq1 = "UPDATE items SET itemSoldFor = '" + soldFor + "' WHERE itemID =  '" + i + "AND itemStatus = 'S' WHERE itemID = " + i + "ANDitemSoldDate = '" + soldDate + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;
//                              String sq2 = "UPDATE items SET itemStatus = 'S' WHERE itemID = " + i;
//                              String sq3 = "UPDATE items SET itemSoldDate = '" + soldDate + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;

                                stmt.executeUpdate(sq1);
//                              stmt.executeUpdate(sq2);
//                              stmt.executeUpdate(sq3);

                                conn.close();

                            } catch (SQLException ex){
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }catch(Exception er){
                                er.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            refreshItemList(conMarker);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "The Consignor wants more money than that man.",
                                    "Not Enough Moola",
                                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }


                    }});//end of sellB action Listener

        conList.addListSelectionListener(

        new ListSelectionListener(){

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

                int conMarker = (int) (conList.getSelectedIndex());


                refreshItemList(conMarker);

//              System.out.println(conMarker);
//              System.out.println(consignerList[conMarker].items.length);
//              if (consignerList[conMarker].hasItems() == true) {
//                  
//              String[] testA;
//              
//              testA = new String[consignerList[conMarker].items.length];
//              
//              for (int i = 0; i < testA.length; i++){
//                  if(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].isSold() == false)
//                  testA[i] = consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemDesc();
//              }
//              
//              itemList.setListData(testA);
//              //itemPane.setViewportView(itemList);
//              } else {
//              //  itemList.setVisible(false);
//              String[] noItems = new String[1];
//              noItems[0] = "No Items for Sale";
//              itemList.setListData(noItems);
//              }

            }

        }


        );//end of conList Listener


        itemList.addListSelectionListener(

        new ListSelectionListener(){

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e){

                int conMarker = (int) (conList.getSelectedIndex());
                int i = (int) itemList.getSelectedIndex();

                itemID = consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemNumber();
                itemIdLabel.setText("Item # " + Integer.toString(itemID));
                itemDesTF.setText(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemDesc());
                categoryCB.setSelectedIndex(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getCategory());
                priceTF.setText(Double.toString(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getSalePrice()));
                lowPriceTF.setText(Double.toString(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getLowBid()));
                commentsTF.setText(consignerList[conMarker].items[conMarker].getComments());        
            }
        });//end of itemList Listener


        outerPanel.setVisible(true);

        return outerPanel;
    }

    public static void refreshItemList(int conMarker){


        if (consignerList[conMarker].hasItems() == true) {

            String[] testA;

            testA = new String[consignerList[conMarker].items.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < testA.length; i++){
                if(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].isSold() == false)
                testA[i] = consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemDesc();
            }

            itemList.setListData(testA);
            //itemPane.setViewportView(itemList);
            } else {
            //  itemList.setVisible(false);
            String[] noItems = new String[1];
            noItems[0] = "No Items for Sale";
            itemList.setListData(noItems);
            }

    }

    public static void refreshConList(){
        consignerList = DatabaseConnector.pullConInfoDB();

        conSampleList = new String[consignerList.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < conSampleList.length; i++){
        conSampleList[i] = "ID " + String.valueOf(consignerList[i].getIdNumber() + "     " + consignerList[i].getLastName() + ", " + consignerList[i].getFirstName());
        }   

        //conList.setListData(conSampleList);
    }

    private class EditHandler implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            String temp = itemIdLabel.getText();
            String temp2 = temp.substring(7);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(temp2);
            conMarker = (int) (conList.getSelectedIndex());




            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "*****", "*******");
                stmt=conn.createStatement();


                String sq1 = "UPDATE items SET itemDesc = '" + itemDesTF.getText() + "' WHERE itemID = " + i + "AND itemSalePrice = " + Double.parseDouble(priceTF.getText()) + " WHERE itemID = " + i + "AND itemLowBid = " + Double.parseDouble(lowPriceTF.getText()) + " WHERE itemID = " + i + "AND itemComments = '" + commentsTF.getText() + "' WHERE itemID = " + i + "AND itemCategory = '" +categoryCB.getSelectedIndex() + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;
//              String sq2 = "UPDATE items SET itemSalePrice = " + Double.parseDouble(priceTF.getText()) + " WHERE itemID = " + i;
//              String sq3 = "UPDATE items SET itemLowBid = " + Double.parseDouble(lowPriceTF.getText()) + " WHERE itemID = " + i;
//              String sq4 = "UPDATE items SET itemComments = '" + commentsTF.getText() + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;
//              String sq5 = "UPDATE items SET itemCategory = '" +categoryCB.getSelectedIndex() + "' WHERE itemID = " + i;

                stmt.executeUpdate(sq1);
//              stmt.executeUpdate(sq2);
//              stmt.executeUpdate(sq3);
//              stmt.executeUpdate(sq4);
//              stmt.executeUpdate(sq5);
                conn.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }catch(Exception er){
                er.printStackTrace();
            }

            refreshConList();
            refreshItemList(conMarker);


        }
    }

    private class SearchingHands implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

            int x = 0;

            try{
                x = Integer.parseInt(searchTF.getText());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Please Enter a Number.",
                        "That is not a Number!!!!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }



            if (x >= 0 && x <= consignerList.length){

                conMarker = x;
                conList.setSelectedIndex(x);
                String[] testA = new String[consignerList[conMarker].items.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < sampleItemA.length; i++){
                    if(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].isSold() == false)
                    testA[i] = consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getItemDesc();
                }

                itemList.setListData(testA);
                itemList.setSelectedIndex(0);

            } else {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Please Enter a Number between 0 & " + (consignerList.length) + ".",
                        "Not In Range!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
            }

        }

    }




}
```

Comment: You have a bad index in the line indicated by the stack trace.

Comment: Any time you have an error like this, it means you're attempting to access an index of the array outside of its range (between zero and however long the array is). In your case, -1 is definitely outside the bounds; look at where the trace is indicating and try to see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getSelectedIndex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) will return a value of `-1` if no value is selected in the `JList` `conList`. Ensure both `JList` components have selected items before attempting to access any fields in the list `consignerList`

```
if (!conList.isSelectionEmpty() && !itemList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It looks like this got edited from conMarker > 0 to the above...I changed it again and it broke it so I switched it back to conMarker > 0 and no problems

Comment: that's an incorrect fix as no action will be taken if you've selected the item at index 0. Please post any new errors messages

Comment: given that youre using both `JLists` to obtain index values, you need to check that both have items selected

Comment: Cool, that seemed to do the trick, its not properly showing my ID's for each item also.  Edit: Got ahead of myself...that seems to have broken the sell button, its now giving me a value of 0 for the error instead of -1 now.  If either an ID has no items OR i click the sell button, both produce the same error value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I found the following around line 497 in your code:

```
    priceTF.setText(Double.toString(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getSalePrice()));
    lowPriceTF.setText(Double.toString(consignerList[conMarker].items[i].getLowBid()));
    commentsTF.setText(consignerList[conMarker].items[conMarker].getComments());
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^
  }
});//end of itemList Listener
```

There are many lines calling `consignerList[conMarker].items[i]` but the last one uses `conMarker` instead of `i`: `consignerList[conMarker].items[conMarker]`.

Comment: That wasn't the only problem, but good catch easy to overlook with all the lines blurring together :)

Comment: So, the `conMarker` index is correct? Or did you fix it and still get the Exceptions?

Comment: I changed it to i and it also added the if statement and it works now with no errors.